# twitter bootstrap modal won't work on first call

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm practicing with twitter bootsrap and made an example website. I use modal view to display warnings when users vote. But it won't display the warning when you vote first time. it displays second time. if you go to [my test site](http://test.erdemece.com/) and click on up arrow you will see nothing will be displayed. but when you click one more time you will see the modal message.(which is saying you have to be logging to vote in my language) I cannot figure out why it's happening. thanks for your help.

this is my jquery.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

              $('.upvote').click( function(event) {

              event.preventDefault();

              var voteID = $(this).attr("id");

                $.ajax({
                  url: "/ajax.php?Page=votetitle",
                  type: "post",
                  dataType: "json",
                  data: {id : voteID, vote: '1'},
                  success: function(data){
                    if(data.success == 'true'){
                      $('#voteresponse'+voteID).html(data.message);
                    }else{
                      $(".upvote").attr("data-toggle", "modal");
                      $(".upvote").attr("data-target", "#modal");

                                      $('#modal').modal('show');
                      $('#modal').on('show', function () {
                        $('.ModalLabel',this).html('Oy verirken hata oluştu!').css({color: 'red'});;
                        $('.modal-body',this).html(data.message);
                      });
                    }
                  },
                  error:function(){
                      $('#voteresponse').popover({
                        title: 'Hata!',
                        content: 'Server hatasi' 
                      });
                  }
                }); 
              });

              $('.downvote').click( function(event) {

              event.preventDefault();

              var voteID = $(this).attr("id");

                $.ajax({
                  url: "/ajax.php?Page=votetitle",
                  type: "post",
                  dataType: "json",
                  data: {id : voteID, vote: '2'},
                  success: function(data){
                    if(data.success == 'true'){
                      $('#voteresponse'+voteID).html(data.message);
                    }else{
                      $(".downvote").attr("data-toggle", "modal");
                      $(".downvote").attr("data-target", "#modal");

                                      $('#modal').modal('show');
                      $('#modal').on('show', function () {
                        $('.ModalLabel',this).html('Oy verirken hata oluştu!').css({color: 'red'});;
                        $('.modal-body',this).html(data.message);
                      });
                    }
                  },
                  error:function(){
                      $('#voteresponse').popover({
                        title: 'Hata!',
                        content: 'Server hatasi' 
                      });
                  }
                }); 
              });
            });
</script>
```

modal html

```
    <div id="modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 class="ModalLabel"></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Kapat</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and buttons

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-mini upvote" id="'.$data['ContentID'].'"><i class="icon-arrow-up"></i></button> 
<span id="voteresponse'.$data['ContentID'].'">'.intval(  $data['TotalVotes'] - $data['VoteSum']  ).'</span>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-mini downvote" id="'.$data['ContentID'].'"><i class="icon-arrow-down"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because those buttons don't even have the data-toggle="modal" attribute before clicking. So the buttons get that attribute only after the first click and can call the modal on second click.

You can try by removing these two lines:

```
 $(".downvote").attr("data-toggle", "modal");
 $(".downvote").attr("data-target", "#modal");
```

and instead just call the modal from your javascript:

```
$('#modal').modal('show');
```

Make sure you put it AFTER the $('#modal').on('show - function..so like this:

```
$('#modal').on('show', function () {
    $('.ModalLabel',this).html('Oy verirken hata oluştu!').css({color: 'red'});;
    $('.modal-body',this).html(data.message);
});
$('#modal').modal('show');
```

As Tallmaris suggested in the comments, placing the event listener in the click handler isn't the best solution, besides I don't think that you even need that listener, so do something like this - change this:

```
$('#modal').on('show', function () {
    $('.ModalLabel',this).html('Oy verirken hata oluştu!').css({color: 'red'});;
    $('.modal-body',this).html(data.message);
});
$('#modal').modal('show');
```

into this:

```
$('.ModalLabel').html('Oy verirken hata oluştu!').css({color: 'red'});;
$('.modal-body').html(data.message);
$('#modal').modal('show');
```

Comment: thank you. this time on the first call modal window comes but not the message unless you click one more time. modal comes empty now.

Comment: Make sure you add that line AFTER putting html.message in modal. I edited my answer to provide clearer explanation.

Comment: it worked! I don't know how you guys know these little things. I want to learn too!!!!!! thanks.

Comment: I would **strongly** suggest to put the event registration outside the main `click()` event handling or you will end up registering the same event every time a user clicks (which is not good!)

Comment: Tallmaris is right. I edited my answer to provide further explanation.

Comment: by the way. after changing event handling the modal comes with no message

Comment: Edited my answer, try removing this from $ selector.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to debug this without knowing if the ajax call is returning `true` or `false`

I did see a line that seems to need the ID tag though.  Not sure if this is the problem.

change: `$(".upvote").attr("data-toggle", "modal");`

to: `$(".upvote").attr("data-toggle", "#modal");`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is what's happening:

```
$(".upvote").attr("data-toggle", "modal");
$(".upvote").attr("data-target", "#modal");
```

In these two lines you are instructing **all** the upvote buttons to become modal toggler. That means that they will trigger the modal window **before** the actual ajax call. The next line:

```
$('#modal').on('show', function () { ... }
```

Is actually registering an event for the modal, and it will register it multiple times!

So you have the two above problems in your code. How to solve? First of all take the event registering outside so you will only hook it once.
Second, remove the two lines that set the `data-toggle` and replace them with just showing the modal:

```
    $('#modal').modal("show");
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: thank you.  
thank you. this time on the first call modal window comes but not the message unless you click one more time. modal comes empty now.

Comment: it's working now. thank you very much. I did not know `$('#modal').modal("show");` hook multiple times.