# Bootstrap modal doesn't toggle on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, onclick, bootstrap-modal

Hi I have the same problem as this thread [twitter bootstrap modal won't work on first call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359914/twitter-bootstrap-modal-wont-work-on-first-call)

I tried to follow the answer and replace `$('#modal').modal('toggle')` to `$('#modal').modal('show')`. It still only registers on the second click. (you have to click on the poster 2  times to show modal, and you have to click on 'Select' button 2 times to close it).

Here's my code: Javascript

```
var zipcode = 92660;
var showDate = '2018-06-10';
var selectedMovieTitles = [];
var selectedMoviePosters = [];
var selectState = false;
var tmsURL = 'http://data.tmsapi.com/v1.1/movies/showings?startDate=' + showDate + '&zip=' + zipcode + '&api_key=' + tmsAPIKey;

$('#button').on('click', function () {
    getMovieList();
});

function litmitMovieSelect() {
    $('#limitSelection').modal('show');
}

function selectMovie() {
    $(this).on('click', function () {
        $('#movieInfoModal').modal('hide');
        if (selectedMovieTitles.length >= 3) {
            litmitMovieSelect();
        }
        else {
            selectState = true;
            selectedMovieTitles.push($(this).attr('data-title'));
            selectedMoviePosters.push($(this).attr('data-poster'));
            $(`.posters[data-title='${$(this).attr('data-title')}']`).css('border', '3px solid #008000');
            $(`.posters[data-title='${$(this).attr('data-title')}']`).attr('data-state-selected', selectState);
            console.log('selected movie titles: ' + selectedMovieTitles);
        }
    });
}

function launchModal() {
    $(this).on('click', function () {
        selectState = false;
        $(this).css('border', '');

        var titleToBeRemove = $(this).attr('data-title');
        if (selectedMovieTitles.indexOf(titleToBeRemove) !== -1) {
            selectedMovieTitles.splice(selectedMovieTitles.indexOf(titleToBeRemove), 1);
        }

        $('.modal-title').text($(this).attr('data-title'));
        var movieInfoDiv = $(`<div>
                                <p><strong>Actors:</strong> ${$(this).attr('data-actors')}</p>
                                <p><strong>Director:</strong> ${$(this).attr('data-director')}</p>
                                <p><strong>Genre:</strong> ${$(this).attr('data-genre')}</p>
                                <p><strong>Year:</strong> ${$(this).attr('data-year')}</p>
                                <p><strong>Duration:</strong> ${$(this).attr('data-runtime')}</p>
                                <p><strong>Rating:</strong> ${$(this).attr('data-rating')}</p>
                                <p><strong>Plot:</strong> ${$(this).attr('data-plot')}</p>
                            </div>`)
        $('.modal-body').html(movieInfoDiv);
        var selectButton = $(`  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-title="${$(this).attr('data-title')}" data-poster="${$(this).attr('data-poster')}">
                                    Select
                                </button>`)
        selectButton.on('click', selectMovie);
        $('#movieInfoModalFooter').html(selectButton);
        $('#movieInfoModal').modal('show');
    });
}

function getMovieList() {
    var movieTitles = [];
    axios.get(tmsURL)
        .then(function (tmsResp) {
            console.log(tmsResp);
            tmsResp.data.forEach(function (element) {
                movieTitles.push(element.title);
            });
            console.log(movieTitles);
            movieTitles.forEach(function (element) {
                var omdbURL = 'https://omdbapi.com/?t=' + element + '&apikey={}';

                axios.get(omdbURL)
                    .then(function (omdbResp) {
                        console.log(omdbResp);
                        var posterDiv = $(`<img class='posters m-3' id='${omdbResp.data.imdbID}' 
                                                data-title='${omdbResp.data.Title}'
                                                data-actors='${omdbResp.data.Actors}'
                                                data-director='${omdbResp.data.Director}'
                                                data-genre='${omdbResp.data.Genre}'
                                                data-plot='${omdbResp.data.Plot}'
                                                data-year='${omdbResp.data.Year}'
                                                data-runtime='${omdbResp.data.Runtime}'
                                                data-rating='${omdbResp.data.imdbRating}'
                                                data-poster='${omdbResp.data.Poster}'
                                                src=${omdbResp.data.Poster}
                                        >`);
                        posterDiv.on('click', launchModal);
                        $('#movie-display').append(posterDiv);
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                    });
            });
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
}
```

Here's the  HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="litmitSelection" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="litmitSelection" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                Sorry, You Can Only Select Up To 3 Movies.
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Movie Info Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="movieInfoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="movieInfoModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" id="movieInfoModalFooter">
                <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> -->
                <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Select</button> -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how many triggers are there in your page for the same modal??

Comment: one for every <img>. When they click on a <img> (poster), it would toggle the modal to display the info of that poster. (at the moment it only trigger if I click that poster twice). Now if I already click that poster twice and toggle the Modal on and off. The next time I only need to click that poster once.

Comment: is the `launchModal()` the problematic function??

Comment: yes. That is the function that binds to each <img>.

Comment: try referencing the element directly instead of `$(this)`

Comment: How would you do that? I only know using $(this) so far.

Comment: you can use `$(".my-class-name")` for elements with classes and `$(#my-id-name)` for elements with ids. the `$(this)` is used to refer to the currently clicked element and is used in conjunction with the class or id selectors

Comment: I'm aware of using class or id to add onclick event listener. But in this case I need to make it dynamic since the function launchModal() applies to all the <img> with different IDs.

Comment: so just give each `<img>` a class like `<img class="movie-poster" ....` and use that for referring to the `<img>` element

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion. I think it works (partially). Before, when I use $(this), it would only work if you click on that poster twice. But now busing class name. It doesn't work on the first poster, but It register on other picture (after the first) on first click. And I understand it because we use the same class for all the poster. So I guess it still need the first click to add on the event listener......

Comment: ok so `partially` means that something else went wrong? am i right?

Comment: I just edited comments above. So technically, the problem still there...

Comment: ok so ive read your updated comment and ive under stood the problem. i will post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would suffice.

**Note**: I assume you are using [bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/) for your project, although bootstrap 3 would work too, just tweak it a bit to suit your needs

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /**
   * for showing edit item popup
   */

  $(document).on('click', "#edit-item", function() {
    $(this).addClass('edit-item-trigger-clicked'); //useful for identifying which trigger was clicked and consequently grab data from the correct row and not the wrong one.

    var options = {
      'backdrop': 'static'
    };
    $('#edit-modal').modal(options)
  })

  // on modal show
  $('#edit-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
    var el = $(".edit-item-trigger-clicked"); // See how its usefull right here? 


    /*
    You now have a reference to which element caused the modal to showup , you can use this to do anything as shown below
    */

    var row = el.closest(".data-row");
    // get the data
    var id = el.data('item-id');
    var name = row.children(".name").text();
    var description = row.children(".description").text();

    // fill the data in the input fields
    $("#modal-input-id").val(id);
    $("#modal-input-name").val(name);
    $("#modal-input-description").val(description);

  })

  // on modal hide
  $('#edit-modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
    $('.edit-item-trigger-clicked').removeClass('edit-item-trigger-clicked')
    $("#edit-form").trigger("reset");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="main-container container-fluid">
  <!-- heading -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h1 class="text-primary mr-auto">Example list</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /heading -->
  <!-- table -->
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="myTable" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th> Name</th>
        <th> Description</th>
        <th> Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="data-row">
        <td class="align-middle iteration">1</td>
        <td class="align-middle name">Name 1</td>
        <td class="align-middle word-break description">Description 1</td>
        <td class="align-middle">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="edit-item" data-item-id="1">edit</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- /table -->
</div>
<!-- Attachment Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="edit-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit-modal-label" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="edit-modal-label">Edit Data</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="attachment-body-content">
        <form id="edit-form" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="">
          <div class="card text-white bg-dark mb-0">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h2 class="m-0">Edit</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <!-- id -->
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-form-label" for="modal-input-id">Id (just for reference not meant to be shown to the general public) </label>
                <input type="text" name="modal-input-id" class="form-control" id="modal-input-id" required>
              </div>
              <!-- /id -->
              <!-- name -->
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-form-label" for="modal-input-name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="modal-input-name" class="form-control" id="modal-input-name" required autofocus>
              </div>
              <!-- /name -->
              <!-- description -->
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-form-label" for="modal-input-description">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="modal-input-description" class="form-control" id="modal-input-description" required>
              </div>
              <!-- /description -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Done</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /Attachment Modal -->
```

Comment: OMG I found the answer. It's pretty simple. I add an extra on click on the launchModal() and selectMovie(). So I remove the onclick inside those 2 functions and now I'm golden. Thanks for your dedicating your time to walk through the problem with me.

Comment: an extra `onclick()`? , please do update your code so that i can see the solution that you've found

Comment: if you notice the first line inside the function launchModal() and selectMovie() -> $(this).on('click',function(){}). I just remove this line in side both functions.

Comment: @ngbaoan oh, ok , well that works out too, happy that your problem got solved